# Virtual sub domains plus additional parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rules which works fine. It simply give me the ability to make virtual sub domains:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /projects/index.php?project=%2 [L,QSA]
```

When it's `project.domain.com` it's totally okay, however, I need to cover up `project.domain.com/first/` to `domain.com/index.php?project=%2&a=first` and `project.domain.com/first/second/` to `domain.com/index.php?project=%2&a=first&b=second`.

I've already tried couple of things, but none of them worked. I can list them but that's gonna be a little bit long with all the description. If anyone could help, that's great, otherwise please comment to update my question with whatever I've already tried and their results.

Comment: @faa `%2` works fine, but when I'm trying to pass the other parameters, then it's not working anymore ... if I want to explain all the things I have already tried, that might be really long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?([^/]+)?/? /projects/index.php?project=%2&a=$1&b=$2  [L,QSA,NC]
```

#### Option

If the redirection is to:

`http://domain.com/index.php?project=%2&a=first&b=second`

as in the last example, replace the previous rewrite rule with this one:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?([^/]+)?/?  http://domain.com/index.php?project=%2&a=$1&b=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```